# Snakes talking?

Tags: animals, parashat-bereishit, speech-talking

I am wondering why snakes no longer talk. The Lord punished the serpent by making him crawl on his belly and eat dust, and be at odds with Eve's offspring, but it does not mention taking away the serpents power of speech.

Why don't snakes talk anymore?

Comment: A preliminary question is whether (1.) snakes as a category could originally speak, (2.) only that individual snake had a unique power of speech, or (3.) that snake was miraculously granted speech temporarily and could not ordinarily speak. See, for example, Radak ([*B'reishis* 3:1](http://books.google.com/books?id=VIAtAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT30#v=onepage&q&f=false)), who discusses these questions as well as yours.

Comment: @Curiosfellow While not a direct answer to your question, you may want to read the 1st chapter in Avot D'Rav Natan. There is a detailed explanation of what the snake actually did as well as how and why it was cursed. I think you'll find it quite interesting

Comment: I dont get the question? Parrots can talk

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty hard to ask any questions from the first two chapters of Genesis, considering both the esoteric nature of both the topic and the fact that the world seems to have rather different back then in a way that may be inherently incomprehensible for us now that we've been evicted from Eden.

That being said, there are several approaches to this question. (The first three here are quoted by the Ibn Ezra)

1. It could be that the snake in the story is not literally a snake, but a metaphor for the Satan, or some similar evil force. The Ibn
       Ezra himself rejects this opinion, though there are several
       midrashim that seem to take this view, despite the obvious problem
       of God punishing the 'snake' by making it crawl on the ground.
2. Chava was a wise enough person to understand snake language (a
   parselmouth, בלע"ז)
3. R. Saadia Gaon says that an angel spoke for the snake, even though
   the 'evil plan' or whatever it was that he did wrong was his own
   fault (the angel just helped give him a voice)
4. Ibn Ezra himself does believe that pre-tree snakes could talk, and
   though he doesn't mention this lack of punishment, he might reply
   that by losing his ability to eat normal food and walk on 'legs' are
   symbolic of becoming less human-like and indicate a loss of the
   ability to speak as well.
5. Abarbanel writes that the snake never actually spoke, and though the
   Torah states that he spoke, it means that he gestured in way that
   his message to Chava was obvious (such as by continually eating from
   the tree, and shoving Chava into it, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe discusses this [at length](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15861&st=&pgnum=21&hilite=) according to Rashi and the plain meaning of the verses (there are others who say that the very ability to speak was something just special for that occasion). He brings up a two possibilities:

- It is obvious. Everyone sees snakes don't talk, so there is no need to specify that this was included. (He rejects this explanation).
- The taking away of the ability to speak is included in the fact that it was cursed more than all other animals. If it retained the ability to speak, it would not be worse than all the other animals.

The second is referenced by the verse saying "Because you did this you will be cursed ..." That which gave it the ability to do entice Chava into the sin is what was removed from it. Both the ability to speak, and its cunning *over* the other animals (thus it became lower than the other animals).

Comment: But everyone sees that snakes crawl on their belly.

Comment: @ClintEastwood, right, that is part of why he rejects it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Moshav Zekanim al haTorah (3:4)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20791&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=) brings that prior to dor haflaga everyone spoke the same language, as the pasuk states: *vayihi khol haarets safa echat udvarim achadim* (bereishis 11:1), ***including the animals***.

After the dispersion took place, everything went south.

Comment: I think this is missing something. After the dor haflagah everyone **spoke** different languages. Now, snakes (and animals) don't speak at all. Unless you mean to imply they can still communicate...also I don't know why the gezeira was on them too...

Comment: So that means people spoke animal language??

Comment: @robev, Everyone began to spoke different languages because we, humans, call our communication 'to speak'. But on regard the animals, they communicate between their species on its own way, differently among each species.

Comment: @FalseMessiah quite the opposite. Back then Lashon Hakodesh was the 'lingua franca'. :)