# Rashi on Adam and on the Snake cunningness

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, rashi, parashat-bereishit, literalism

The snake was able to speak from its creation ([Likutei Sichos (10) p. 13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15861&st=&pgnum=21)) so why is man singled out as being capable of speech ([דעה ודבור acc. to Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.2.7.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) if the snake already had it?

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%205%20Krakowski.pdf

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57525/the-serpent-of-gan-eden and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9243/do-religious-jews-generally-believe-the-serpent-of-garden-of-eden-was-satan